# How to extract single value from json?

Tags: python, json

I am using simplejson

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

def query_reviews (query):
    url = "http://......."
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url) 
    values=json.loads(response)
```

Now i want to take out specific value out of the output what i get.

So how can i do this? I have already searched a lot but not getting my issue resolved.Kindly help me out.

Comment: I think I've fixed your formatting. Please check to ensure it is accurate

Comment: which value do you want to get, please give an example

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the json format

if it's an array, this will work

```
try:
import json
import urllib2
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

def query_reviews ():
    url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twitter/typeahead.js/gh-pages/data/countries.json"
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    values=json.loads(response.read())
    needle = 'Yemen'
    for value in values:
        if value == needle:
            print 'Found it!'
            print value

query_reviews()
```

If it's a dictionary use
values['key'] like so:

```
try:
    import json
    import urllib2
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

def query_reviews ():
    url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bitergia/apache-cloudstack-dashboard/master/data/json/-its-dom-top-closers.json"
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    values=json.loads(response.read())
    print values['id']

query_reviews()
```

Answer (score 0):

I completely depends on the JSON you loaded.  If it's a dict, the value is imported into a Python dict.

```
# JSON is {"game": "pacman", "year": 1988, "highscore": 123456}
print values['highscore']
```

If you have a complex hierarchy, that will be a dict of dicts.

```
# JSON is {"games": {"pacman": {"year": 1988, "highscore": 123456}},
#                   {"defender": {"highscore": 345798, "year": 1983}}, ...
print values['games']['pacman']['highscore']
```

If there are lists involved, you just index.

```
# JSON is [ {"game": "pacman", "year": 1988, "highscore": 123456},
#           {"game:" "defender", "highscore": 345678", "year": 1983}, ...
print values[0]['highscore']
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good; it may help to start with

```
pprint.pprint(values)  # after 'import pprint'
```

... and that will show you what the data you are getting looks like.